# AngularJS Spring MVC Redirection with data binding

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to AngularJS and the question may not be very smart.

I am trying to redirect to a new page with data-binding from Spring Controller.

My requirement is that when I click on a button/hyperlink on a page (say page 1), my Spring Controller performs business and determines which page to display (either page 2 or page 3). The data in the redirected page is populated from Spring Controller during redirection using query params.

My problem is that the page redirects just fine. But I am unable to retrieve the query params in AngularJS, though I can view them in the redirection request URL in browser (Google developer tools).

I have only added the relevant code :

Controller method called from first jsp page (say page1.jsp) to redirect to page2 (pageToRedirectTo.jsp)

In page1.jsp, there is a button that calls the method for page redirection along with form object.

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.onClickOfPage1ButtonRedirect ()">Page Redirect</button>
```

app.js

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp',[]);
```

AngularJs Controller

```
this.onClickOfPage1ButtonRedirect = function(){

        Page1Service.redirectToNewPage()
        .then(
                function(d) {
                    $scope.myVal = d;
                    var e1 = angular.element(document.getElementById("dir"));
                   e1.html(d);
                   $compile(e1.contents())($scope);

               },
                function(errResponse){
                     console.error('Error.');
                } 
    );


    };
```

AngularJS Service that sends request to Spring Controller

Page1Service.js

```
angularApp.factory('Page1Service', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    return {
 redirectToNewPage: function() {
                    return $http.post('/requestMappingUrlFromPage1')
                            .then(
                                    function(response){
                                        return response.data;
                                    }, 
                                    function(errResponse){

                                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                    }
                            );
            }

 };

}]);
```

Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestMappingUrlFromPage1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirectToNewPage(){

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        List<ResponseDTO> responseDTO = new ArrayList<ResponseDTO>();
        //Business logic to populate responseDTO list ....



          String responseJson=  new Gson().toJson(responseDTO);
         UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/pageToRedirectTo");
                 UriComponents uriComponents =  b.queryParam("responseDTOList", responseJson).build();

         return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);

    }
```

Now, when I get the response in Page1Service.js, it displays the response.data as the html content of the page being redirected to. In Google Chrome developer tools, I can see the query parameters :

```
responseDTOList:[{"parameter1":"123","parameter2":"Name","parameter3":false,"parameter4":false},{"parameter1":"123123","parameter2":"Name1","parameter3":false,"parameter4":false}]
```

Response received in Page1Service.js

```
Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html ng-app="angularApp">
↵<head>
.......
↵</body>
↵
↵</html>", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

Is there a way to retrieve this data?

I have tried using $route.params, but it is undefined. Also, I am not using ng-route. Using $location is also not useful as all my pages are dynamically embedded in the custom dir tag in home page, so $location.absUrl() always gives the home page url.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!!

I have added the browser header params that shows the response object in my Query Params. Angular response.data, however, displays just the HTML content, and I am unable to retrieve the query params.

Link to view the Browser headers : [browser headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9FSP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of it is possible to retrieve response data from query parameters in AngularJS.

However, I solved my problem by retrieving the query params in the GET request of the redirected page in Spring Controller. Then, I am sending it back to Angular Service via the HttpServletResponse header and retrieving it back in AngularJS.

Probably not the ideal solution, but that's the fix I could find in a short period without major restructuring of my code.

Spring Controller for redirection from page1 to page2

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestMappingUrlFromPage1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> redirectToNewPage(){

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    List<ResponseDTO> responseDTO = new ArrayList<ResponseDTO>();
    //Business logic to populate responseDTO list ....



      String responseJson=  new Gson().toJson(responseDTO);
     UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/pageToRedirectTo");
             UriComponents uriComponents =  b.queryParam("responseDTOList", responseJson).build();

     return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);

}
```

Redirected Page Controller mapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/pageToRedirectTo",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getpageToRedirectTo(@RequestParam(required=false, name="responseDTOList")String temp, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {


        try{
        if(temp!=null){ 
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
             //JSON from String to Object
             List<ResponseDTO> objList = mapper.readValue(temp,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,ResponseDTO.class));


             if(objList!=null){

                String jsonList = new Gson().toJson(objList);
                 response.setHeader("responseDTOList", jsonList);
             }

        }
        }catch(JsonMappingException jme){
            logger.error("JsonMappingException : ", jme);
        }catch(JsonParseException jpe){
            logger.error("JsonParseException : ", jpe);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            logger.error("IOException : ", ioe);
        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Error : ", e);

        }


         return "pageToRedirectTo";
     }
```

Page1Service.js

```
angularApp.factory('Page1Service', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
return {
    redirectToNewPage: function() {
                return $http.post('/requestMappingUrlFromPage1')
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                   var customResponse = {};

                                customResponse.responseDTOList= response.headers('responseDTOList'); 
                                customResponse.pageData = response.data;
                                return customResponse;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){

                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        }};}]);
```

AngularJS Controller

```
this.onClickOfPage1ButtonRedirect = function(){
    Page1Service.redirectToNewPage()
    .then(
            function(d) {
                $scope.responseList = d.responseDTOList;
                $scope.myVal = d.pageData;
                var e1 = angular.element(document.getElementById("dir"));
               e1.html(d);
               $compile(e1.contents())($scope);

           },
            function(errResponse){
                 console.error('Error.');
            } 
);


};
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea which pop in my head after examine your problem is that the one way of achieving your target is to convert `angularJS` page into `Thymeleaf` page. Its very simple to convert it and your all `angularJS` code will remain same. Please see [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) doc for this purpose.

Then simply you can get params in js script like this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = [[${message}]];
    console.log(message);

  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Once you got your parms in `Javascript` then you can easily get into `angularJS` Controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Muhammad Suleman, but I cannot change from angularJS to Thymeleaf due to the project requirement constraints.

Comment: But I guess Thymeleaf page is equally valid for all angularJS pages. Its like harmless for them. Actually I have faced similar problem and this was the workaround. Yes of course choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting Page1Service.js response.data as HTML you can use JSON.parse to parse the content and get data.
it will be helpful to provide ans if you make it more clear "when I get the response in Page1Service.js, it displays the response.data as the html content **of the page being redirected to**."

Comment: I have already added the response that I receive in response.data in Page1Service.js                                                                                                          

Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html ng-app="angularApp">
↵<head>
.......
↵</body>
↵
↵</html>", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}


I have also added the link to the image showing the header parameters in the browser.